# Rails 3: Why is flatten duplicating records with more than one associated record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Associations:

- Shipment has many invoices
- Invoice belongs to shipment

I get a list of shipments like this...

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:invoices).where(:customer_id => @customer.id).where("customer_open_balance <> 0").where("bill_to IS NULL").order("file_number ASC")
```

Then I flatten like this...

```
@invoices = @shipments.map(&:invoices).flatten
```

I get duplicates. For example, I do the shipments query right above this line, `@shipments.count` I get 5 results.

Then after I flatten, if there is a shipment that had two invoices, it duplicates them and I get 4 instead of two `@invoices.count` I get 7 (should still be 5).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I apologize. I just updated the title to read as a question. I believe I can fix my issue by doing `@invoices.uniq!`, but I'm afraid it will remove legitimate shipments or invoices. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried adding uniq to the Shipment.joins... query?

Comment: `@invoices.uniq` (without a bang) won't modify `@invoices` or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `joins` the records returned can be duplicates. So if `Tree` has many `leaves` then `Tree.joins(:leaves).count` will be equal to number of leaves and with lot of duplicates records of a `tree`. This is  because `joins` is calling sql's `INNER JOIN` which returns an intersection of the two tables.

From [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#joining-a-single-association):

> Category.joins(:posts)
>
> Or, in English: “return a Category object for all categories with
>   posts”. Note that you will see duplicate categories if more than one
>   post has the same category. If you want unique categories, you can use
>   Category.joins(:post).select(“distinct(categories.id)”).

So for you case something like this would work:

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:invoices).where(:customer_id => @customer.id).where("customer_open_balance <> 0").where("bill_to IS NULL").order("file_number ASC").
             select("distinct(shipments.id)")
```

Another way to do it would be by using `group`

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:invoices).where(:customer_id => @customer.id).where("customer_open_balance <> 0").where("bill_to IS NULL").order("file_number ASC").
             group("shipments.id")
```

I prefer `group` as the `select` statement in Rails is sometimes ignored when chaining with other scopes.

PS: if your query does not have any conditions on `invoices` then try using `includes` instead of `joins`. This would `eagerload` all invoices with one query instead of making a separate query for each `shipment`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.uniq` to the initial query:

```
@shipments = Shipment.uniq.joins(:invoices).where(:customer_id => @customer.id).where("customer_open_balance <> 0").where("bill_to IS NULL").order("file_number ASC")
```